# Plotting NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

`Plot[E^(-0.5 x) NIntegrate[Cos[t] E^(Cos[t] + 0.5 t), {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 40}]`

Mathematica evaluates this integral for each point, which takes a long time. It is possible to iterate each time step without going through the whole function. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Consider using `NDSolve[]` instead…

Comment: That is as answered as this question can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To flesh out GuessWho's suggestion:

```
sol[t_] = NDSolveValue[{Cos[t] E^(Cos[t] + 0.5 t) == f'[t], f[0] == 0}, f[t], {t, 0, 40}]

Show[
  Plot[E^(-0.5 x) NIntegrate[Cos[t] E^(Cos[t] + 0.5 t), {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 40}]
  Plot[E^(-0.5 t) sol[t], {t, 0, 40}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second plot is about 300 times faster than the first one.

Comment: …and thanks for following through! :)

Comment: my pleasure, as always

Comment: I was am used to Evaluate[y[x]/.sol] (that's how documentation does it). Are there any difference (cause your way is far better it seems)?

Comment: I believe your question is answered in the Properties & Relations section of the NDSolveValue doc page. This relatively new function precisely aims at shortening this usage pattern.